# Call Getter again after set on TwoWay Binding TextBox

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a string property that performs some formatting on a decimal value and I'm binding my textbox to it, on TwoWay mode. When the TextBox loses focus, the setter method of the property is called and i would like to have my getter property to get called again. Is that possible? I've tried the UpdateSource on the binding on the LostFocus event and calling OnPropertyChanged, but both didn't work.

Here's some code:

```
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public string ValueParsed
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeParse(Value);
        }
        set
        {
            Value = SomeParse(value);
        }
    }
```

and my xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValueParsed, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`OnPropertyChanged(<property name>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in property setter which will notify *UI*:

```
public string ValueParsed
{
    get
    {
        return SomeParse(Value);
    }
    set
    {
        this.Value = SomeParse(value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ValueParsed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it and, I didn't found out why, sometimes the screen didn't receive back the value... So, i've changed the method I was formatting the string based on TextChanged and other events and I've got the result I was looking for

Comment: I think maybe you should let the setter just do 'this.Value=value; this.OnPropertyChanged("ValueParsed");
Since the getter is transforming it using SomeParse.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, but the OnPropertyChanged is not sending back do the screen when in two way binding. Any ideas why?